# Redirect sveltekit endpoint and pass data to page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using oauth to signin to a service. Once signed in, the app redirects my app to the set redirect uri, which also points to my sveltekit endpoint (/callback). After I verify the code and get the token through the endpoint, I'd like to redirect/send the client back to the homepage, with the token data, but I cannot figure out how to.

What I've currently tried:

```js
export async function get(response: IncomingRequest) {
    if (response.query.has('code')) {
        const code = response.query.get('code')
        const url = `url endpoint to verify code above`

        const verifiedCode = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
        })

        if (verifiedCode) {
            const data = await verifiedCode.json()
            // redirect to homepage and give token to client
            // tried:
            return {
                headers: {
                    location: '/'
                },
                body: data,
                status: 302
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Logging the response in the `get()` endpoint of my homepage results in the body being null regardless of what I put the body in this endpoint.

Comment: Sounds related to https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1711

Answer (score 1):

If you would like an easy way to access the token value that was generated by the OAuth provider on the client side then you can add that information as a query parameter in the redirect request.

So you can keep everything like you have it, just add that token information to the location value.  Let's assume that verifiedCode is an object that looks like this:

```
const verifiedCode = {
    access_code: "eydkfsladkljdks..."
}
```

Then you can just add that key value pair like so:

```
export async function get(response: IncomingRequest) {
    if (response.query.has('code')) {
        const code = response.query.get('code')
        const url = `url endpoint to verify code above`

        const verifiedCode = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json' }
        })

        if (verifiedCode) {
            const data = await verifiedCode.json()
            // redirect to homepage and give token to client
            // tried:
            return {
                headers: {
                    location: `/?access_token=${verifiedCode.access_token}`
                },
                body: data,
                status: 302
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query param will be then accessible from index.svelte using the $page store.  Use $page.query.get('access_token') to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you expecting to handle `body: data` on the client side? The homepage? As soon as the client browser receives a 302, it will start to navigate.

The correct way would be to send a "set-cookie" as part of the HTTP 302 header. The client browser will save this cookie and also send it with any future request towards the server. Obviously, it can also access it.

In the case below the client browser will name the cookie "token" and assuming your token or `verifiedCode` has an expiry date, you could set that as well (in seconds) as `Max-Age`.

```
return {
    headers: {
        location: '/',
        'set-cookie': `token=${data}; SameSite=Strict; Max-Age=${tokenAge}`
    },
    status: 302
}
```

If you want to receive the `verifiedCode` on the server again whenever the user calls an endpoint, you could read it with `response.headers.cookie`.